# Build JS from SJSIR `manually`

Tags: javascript, scala, scala.js

I need to build a js file from sjsir files at runtime to implement a system of plugins, so that it can't be done at compile time with the rest of my compilation. I used to implement the same process in 0.6.3 with the following code, but it seems to be deprecated. What algorithm do you recommand to achieve the same action with 0.6.13 ?
Thanks

```scala
val scalajsLib = copyJar("scalajs-library_2.11-0.6.3")

val semantics = org.scalajs.core.tools.sem.Semantics.Defaults

val partialClasspath =
  PartialClasspathBuilder.build(collection.immutable.Seq(scalajsLib, src))

val completeClasspath = partialClasspath.resolve()

val optimizer = new ScalaJSOptimizer(semantics)

val logger = new ScalaConsoleLogger

val out = WritableFileVirtualJSFile(
    new java.io.File(target, JS_FILE))
if (optimized) {
  val sems = semantics.optimized

  new ScalaJSClosureOptimizer(sems).optimizeCP(
    new ScalaJSOptimizer(sems),
    completeClasspath,
    ScalaJSClosureOptimizer.Config(out),
    logger
  )
} else {
  optimizer.optimizeCP(
    completeClasspath,
    ScalaJSOptimizer.Config(out, checkIR = false, wantSourceMap = !optimized),
    logger
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tools API has dramatically changed in 0.6.5, indeed. It became much simpler and more able to evolve in non-breaking ways in the future.

Your code above can be written with the new API as follows:

```scala
import java.io.File

import org.scalajs.core.tools.io._
import org.scalajs.core.tools.sem._
import org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.backend.{OutputMode, ModuleKind}
import org.scalajs.core.tools.linker.Linker
import org.scalajs.core.tools.logging.ScalaConsoleLogger

def link(inputClasspath: Seq[File], outputJSFile: File): Unit = {
  // Obtain VirtualScalaJSIRFile's from the input classpath
  val irCache = new IRFileCache().newCache
  val irContainers = IRFileCache.IRContainer.fromClasspath(inputClasspath)
  val sjsirFiles = irCache.cached(irContainers)

  // A bunch of options. Here we use all the defaults
  val semantics = Semantics.Defaults
  val outputMode = OutputMode.Default
  val moduleKind = ModuleKind.NoModule
  val linkerConfig = Linker.Config()

  // Actual linking
  val linker = Linker(semantics, outputMode, moduleKind, linkerConfig)
  val logger = new ScalaConsoleLogger
  linker.link(sjsirFiles, WritableFileVirtualJSFile(outputJSFile), logger)
}
```

And you can call that `link` function with the following arguments, to exactly match your above snippet:

```scala
link(Seq(scalajsLib, src), new java.io.File(target, JS_FILE))
```

If you intend to call this method several times on the same classpath within the same process, it is advised to cache and reuse the instances `irCache` and `linker` across runs, as this will considerably speed up the process.

See also [the Scaladoc of the Tools API](https://www.scala-js.org/api/scalajs-tools/latest/#org.scalajs.core.tools.package).

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to prevent from errors about class repetition in the batch of sjsir (which generates the message: XXX `already seen`) at link time ? I guess it is, since this error does not occur when the build is done at compile time from the build.sbt.